# jquery Enter as Tab is not working in Firefox but working fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have made this script below is working fine in chrome by the help of someone in stackoverflow.

```
(function($) {
$.fn.enterAsTab = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        'allowSubmit': false
    }, options);
    $(this).find('input, select, textarea, button').on("keypress", {localSettings: settings}, function(event) {
        if (settings.allowSubmit) {
            var type = $(this).attr("type");
            if (type == "submit") {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(":input:visible:not(:disabled):not([readonly])");
            var idx = inputs.index(this);
            if (idx == inputs.length - 1) {
                idx = -1;
            } else {
                inputs[idx + 1].focus(); // handles submit buttons
            }
            try {
                inputs[idx + 1].select();
            }
            catch (err) {
                // handle objects not offering select
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    return this;
};
```

})(jQuery);

But this code is not fully working in Firefox. The not working part is the select. I cannot use enter to move to next field when I am in a dropdown (Select).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`event.keycode` is not supported by Firefox. You need to use `event.which` for Firefox.

Take a look: [window.event.keyCode how to do it on Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116933/window-event-keycode-how-to-do-it-on-firefox)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. The problem is only in dropdown (select), on buttons, textarea and textfields are working fine. Hence, I think the keyCode should be okay. I have changed to which as well but still the same. Someone has made the code here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dmvEy