# This piece of javascript code is working in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I have a created a calculator using Jquery and Javascript, everything works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox.

```
function validate(x, y, z) {
if ((isNaN(x) || x == "") || (isNaN(y) || y == "")) {
return "Please Enter A Valid Number";
} else if (z == "/" && y == 0) {
return "Divide By zero error";
} else if (event.keyCode == 32) {
return false;
} else {
return calculation(x, y, z);
}
}
```

[Demo Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WoTwvHUc8JLan7De41Fd?p=preview)

Comment: I think the problem is with event.keycode . Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6117105/1324935

Comment: Also you should use `===` to compare with `0` or `""`

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on `window.event`. It is a Microsoftism that not all browsers implement. However, each handler will receive the event as a parameter. Use it explicitly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#first").focus();
  $('#first,#second,#oper').keyup(function(evt) {
    // HERE                                ^^^
    $('#demo').html(validate(evt.keyCode, $('#first').val(), $('#second').val(), $('#oper').val()));
    // and HERE              ^^^^^^^^^^^
  });
});

function validate(key, x, y, z) {
  // and HERE     ^^^
  if ((isNaN(x) || x == "") || (isNaN(y) || y == "")) {
    return "Please Enter A Valid Number";
  } else if (z == "/" && y == 0) {
    return "Divide By zero error";
  } else if (key == 32) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return calculation(x, y, z);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/uJB3W7bnL1jXEAK5IJxF?p=preview)

```
          $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#first").focus();
          $('#first,#second,#oper').keyup(function(event) {
            $('#demo').html(validate(event,$('#first').val(), $('#second').val(), $('#oper').val()));
          });
        });

        function validate(event,x, y, z) {
          if ((isNaN(x) || x == "") || (isNaN(y) || y == "")) {
            return "Please Enter A Valid Number";
          } else if (z == "/" && y == 0) {
            return "Divide By zero error";
          } else if (event.keyCode == 32) {
            return false;
          } else {
            return calculation(x, y, z);
          }
        }
```