# onkeydown with jquery and javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 Web App and I have this html:

```
<div class="group">
    <input type="text"
            class="productClass"
            name="Configurations[0].RemainingCodes"
            id="Configurations[0].RemainingCodes"
            onkeydown='IsValidKey(event);'
            required />
</div>
```

And this Javascript function:

```
function IsValidKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var code = e.keyCode;

    return (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46 || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105);
}
```

But it doesn't work although I can get keycode in `code` variable. I'm trying to allow only numbers [0..9] key and backspace, but I can type letters.

The first version was this:

And javascript:

```
function IsValidKey()
{
    return (window.event.keyCode >= 48 && window.event.keyCode <= 57) || window.event.keyCode == 8 || window.event.keyCode == 46 || (window.event.keyCode >= 96 && window.event.keyCode <= 105);
}
```

But FireFox complains about `window.event` doesn't exist.

I need to be able to run this code on as much as possible browsers.

And this is not a duplicate because I'm getting the code in Firefox and the function allows to enter letters.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.event.keyCode how to do it on Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116933/window-event-keycode-how-to-do-it-on-firefox)

Comment: `onkeydown='return IsValidKey(event);'`

Comment: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsValidKey(this)` does not pass in the `event` object, it is passing in the html element. To pass in the event you have to specify `event` like: `IsValidKey(this,event)`. Also you have to use `return` in your inline js, otherwise you need to call `evt.preventDefault()` in your callback.

```js
function IsValidKey(element,evt) {
  var event = ((window.event) ? (window.event) : (evt));
  
  return (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || 
         event.keyCode == 8 || 
         event.keyCode == 46 || 
         (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown='return IsValidKey(this,event);' />
```

Or instead of using inline js you could use `addEventListener`, or jQuery's `.keydown` method to add your listeners and the `event` object will get passed in automatically

```
document.querySelector("#inputID").addEventListener("keydown",IsValidKey);
//OR jQuery("#inputID").keydown(isValidKey);
function IsValidKey(evt) {
/*.... rest of code ....*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code in Firefox:

```
key = event.which;
```

Answer (score 0):

I always do it this way in jQuery and haven't had problems with browser support.

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
        var c = e.which;
        e.preventDefault;
        return (c >= 48 && c <= 57) || c == 8 || c == 46 || (c >= 96 && c <= 105);
    });
```

As to why Firefox is complaining about `window.event` - browsers have different event models, and as far as I know, `window.event` simply doesn't exist in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks, but there is something on that function that allow me to type letters.

Answer (score 0):

Based on an answer that someone posted but he/she deleted it, this is my solution:

```
function IsValidKey(e) {
    var c = e.which;

    if (!((c >= 48 && c <= 57) || c == 8 || c == 46 || (c >= 96 && c <= 105)))
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="group">
    <input type="text"
            class="productClass"
            name="Configurations[0].PkgRatio"
            id="Configurations[0].PkgRatio"
            onkeydown='IsValidKey(event);'
            required />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to return the boolean in the onkeydown attribute:
 onkeydown='return IsValidKey(event);'

If the event handler is returning false is blocking the propagation of the event, or the bubbling up.

See this answer too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4379459/4768374