# event.charCode doesn't works in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, mozilla

I'm trying to restrict my text field for numbers only.
I'm using:

```
onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)"
```

The troubles appears when I want delete (using backspace o delete key) or move my cursor in another position using arrow keys, cause I can't use these keys.

So now, I have this code:

```
onkeypress="return ((event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || event.charCode == 8)"
```

It is an example, charCode == 8 is for allow backspace. It doesn't work in Firefox. I'm still restricting text field to numbers, but I still can't use my backspace key.

Can you give me a hand? Do you know what are I'm doing wrong?

Keycode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: You might consider attaching event handlers properly using proper Javascript instead of with inline handlers (which are as bad as `eval` and hard to work with)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116933/window-event-keycode-how-to-do-it-on-firefox

Comment: And consider adding keys 96 to 105.

Answer (score 2):

Use `event.which`

```html
<input onkeypress="return ((event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) || event.which == 8)">
```

---

Alternatively you could use `event.key` and use actual key names to test for validity.

```js
function handleNumericEditable(event){
  var allowed = /^[0-9]|Arrow(Left|Right)|Backspace|Home|End|Delete$/
  return allowed.test(event.key);
}
```

```html
<input onkeypress="return handleNumericEditable(event)">
```