# Getting key code in Firefox from webforms textbox keydown event

Tags: javascript, events, webforms, keydown, keycode

My textbox is declared thus:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtShowManyItemTag" CssClass="price" onkeydown="return txtShowManyItemTagKeyUp(this);" TabIndex= "997" runat="server" Text="" Width="50px"   />
```

The javascript function called is:

```
function txtShowManyItemTagKeyUp(txt) {
    if (window.event.keyCode == 13 && txt.value != '') {
        var nextRow = $(txt).closest('tr').next();
        if (nextRow.length > 0) {
            $(txt).closest('tr').next().find(".price").select();
        }
        else {
            $("#<%=btnOkMany.ClientID %>").select();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

In Chrome and IE, the window.event.keyCode == 13 correctly detects the Enter key being pressed, but I have been unable to find the equivalent for Firefox.  Note that I am not passing an event, I'm passing the control that's triggering the event, and I can find no way to get the key code from that object.  I'm going through stack overflow, but have not yet found something that matches this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.event.keyCode how to do it on Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116933/window-event-keycode-how-to-do-it-on-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `onkeydown` attribute, use

```
$("#txtShowManyItemTag").on('keydown', txtShowManyItemTagKeyUp);
```

And declare the function as

```
function txtShowManyItemTagKeyUp(e) { ... }
```

Inside it, you can now use `e` to refer to the event, and `this` to refer to the `<input>`.